# Date format in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am displaying date in this format using angular

```
{{ date }} ,date:\'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss\
```

how to display like  `Jan-dd-yyyy` using angular

Is there any dirct way to do using angular js- (Using normal jquery i am able to do)

Comment: Please refer this link friend http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date may be this one help you

Comment: Hi i created some custom filters and updated here http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use Angular filter of date.

```
{{date  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss'}}
```

See the following link.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:date

Comment: it should be `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 2):

Well,

according to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate), you have a builtin filter in angular, called `date`:

```
<p>{{Date.now() | date:'yyyy'}}
```

would render to:

```
<p>2013</p>
```

The `yyyy`in this case can be any format string documented. In the example you gave, this would be:

```
{{date | date: 'MMM-dd-yyyy'}} # => "Jan-21-2013" (if date was a date object for this day)
```

Answer (score 2):

**For custom date:**

```
$scope.user.dob = new Date('1980', '12' ,'10');  // controller code

 {{user.dob | date : 'MMM-dd-yyyy'}}  // Dec-10-1980
```

**For current date:**

```
 $scope.user.current= new Date();  // controller code

 {{user.current | date : 'MMM-dd-yyyy'}}  // Current date in given format
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 {{ date }} ,date:\'MMM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss\
```

Comment: Should be `HH:mm:ss`, you have months instead of minutes