# angularjs : format API return date into dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: angularjs, date

I am using angular for developing an hybrid Mobile Application.

I am getting date from Api like this `Date : "2017/12/15"` but i need to format it into inside expression because i am using ng-repeat to push data in view.

I need to formate it like 15-Dec-2017 or 15-12-2017.

I have tried `{{data.Date | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}` but this approach is not working.

I followed these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004255/how-do-i-format-data-in-a-view-in-angularjs) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694041/date-format-in-angular-js) but none of these resolving my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not working because your date is in string format.

Convert it to date format like this

```
$scope.toDate=function(strDt){
 return new Date(strDt);
}
```

html

```
{{toDate(data.Date) | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/zLbawtj3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Its `type` manipulation minor mistake! See following fixed snippet.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.dateObj = function(stringDate) {
    //receives string but returns date object on which filter can be applied
    return new Date(stringDate);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>
    {{ dateObj("2020/12/06") | date : 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Zeeshan Hassan Memon